# Android Change Navigation View Menu Background

Tags: android, view, menu, background, navigation

In my app i want to change the navigation view menu background, but i dont know how to do this. All posts i have watched explains how to change each menu item background, but all i need is to change the entire background of the menu.

This is what i want to change, the entire white background:

[image]

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Is there anyway to change the white background from the activity_main_drawer layout?

activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can set background to your `NavigationView` to change its color like below (set to app_white ) & for header set any color as a background of drawer_header_layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/adcl_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/app_white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_layout"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/app_secondary_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/app_secondary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: but, I need image background, if I set like this, its overlapped by header

Answer (score 7):

just add `android:background="@color/yourColor"` to the `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`.